# How to install ns2 and ns3 together?

Tags: 16.04, ns2

Can I install `ns2` and `ns3` together in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the installed files for each package you will see that both can happily exist on the same system with no potentially overwritten files or duplicate filenames:

**1. ns2**

```
/usr/bin/calcdest
/usr/bin/dec-tr-stat
/usr/bin/epa-tr-stat
/usr/bin/nlanr-tr-stat
/usr/bin/ns
/usr/bin/nse
/usr/bin/nstk
/usr/bin/setdest
/usr/bin/ucb-tr-stat
/usr/share/doc/ns2/README
/usr/share/doc/ns2/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/ns2/TODO.html
/usr/share/doc/ns2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ns2/copyright
/usr/share/doc/ns2/release_steps.txt
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/ns2
/usr/share/man/man1/ns.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/nse.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/nstk.1.gz
```

**2. ns3**

```
/usr/bin/ns3.22-bench-packets
/usr/bin/ns3.22-bench-simulator
/usr/bin/ns3.22-print-introspected-doxygen
/usr/bin/ns3.22-raw-sock-creator
/usr/bin/ns3.22-tap-creator
/usr/bin/ns3.22-tap-device-creator
/usr/share/doc/ns3/README
/usr/share/doc/ns3/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/ns3/RELEASE_NOTES.gz
/usr/share/doc/ns3/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ns3/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/ns3
```

And I have run a test install of *both* on my Xenial Xerus system:

```
sudo apt-get install ns2 ns3
```

with absolutely *no* installation issues...

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Packages: ns2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/ns2/filelist)
- [Ubuntu Packages: ns3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/ns3/filelist)

Comment: @Sousou So hopefully this answer has adequately answered your issue? If so you can 'Accept' the answer by clicking on the tick or check mark near the answer. This signifies for future readers that this was the most correct answer. And have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do `sudo apt-get install ns2 ns3` and have them both installed, yes.